# Dropzone.js - Show button on queued files lenght > 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropzone.js

I'm new to Dropzone.js and i was wondering if there is a way to show the Processing button when i add or remove a new file on the list. Here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="dropz" class="dropzone">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info pull-right" id="uploadFiles" style="display:none">Upload</button>
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#dropz", {
    url: "@Url.Action("AddFiles")",
    addRemoveLinks: true,                      
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    maxFiles: 5,
    parallelUploads: 5,
    init: function() {
        this.on("addedfile", function (file) {
            //Here is what i tried, but the alert result is undefined
            if (myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().lenght > 0)
                 alert(myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().lenght);
                 $('#uploadFiles').css('display','block');
        });
    }
    });

    $('#uploadFiles').on('click', function () {
        myDropzone.processQueue();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Misspelled word `lenght` is `length`, use console for debugging:

```
if (myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length > 0) {
     console.log(myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length);
     $('#uploadFiles').css('display','block');
}
```